# js loses bytes in serial(com port)

Tags: javascript

i trying make connection between browser and arduino, and get problems.
Sometimes first char of reading stream is loses. Always the first few strings is normal, but other pakages in random order can be normal, or not.

I noticed about var done never can be a TRUE.

```
const reader = port.readable.getReader();

// Listen to data coming from the serial device.
while (true) {
  const { value, done } = await reader.read();
  if (done) {
    // Allow the serial port to be closed later.
    reader.releaseLock();
    break;
  }
  // value is a Uint8Array.
  console.log(value);
}
```

I use code from  [official source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SerialPort#reading_data_from_a_port), also i try make biger bufer size, or put create custom bufer l[ike this](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/serial/#:%7E:text=Here%27s%20an%20example%20of%20how%20to%20reuse%20the%20buffer%20out%20of).

Comment: `value` will not be printed if `done` is true. Could that be the problem…?

Comment: Done may be true, if  get all string. I lose only first char